# Statistical test on multiple variables on multiple lists (tibble)

Tags: r, dplyr, tibble, rstatix

To simplify my data analysis I need to process different statistical tests (in that example a shapiro test) on different different variables and on different groups of data. The purpose is to not write 150 times the same code. To do that I created, from my dataset, a tibble where each list correspond to a group of data.

The dataset:

```
dput(head(PdataLaKo,25)) 
structure(list(ctd_file = c("2018-08-02T162038 SBE0251090", "2018-08-02T162038 SBE0251090", 
"2018-08-02T162038 SBE0251090", "2018-08-02T162038 SBE0251090", 
"2018-08-02T162038 SBE0251090", "2018-08-02T162038 SBE0251090", 
"2018-08-02T162038 SBE0251090", "2018-08-02T162038 SBE0251090", 
"2018-08-02T162038 SBE0251090", "2018-08-02T162038 SBE0251090", 
"2018-08-02T175518 SBE0251090", "2018-08-02T175518 SBE0251090", 
"2018-08-02T175518 SBE0251090", "2018-08-02T175518 SBE0251090", 
"2018-08-02T175518 SBE0251090", "2018-08-02T175518 SBE0251090", 
"2018-08-02T175518 SBE0251090", "2018-08-02T175518 SBE0251090", 
"2018-08-02T175518 SBE0251090", "2018-08-02T175518 SBE0251090", 
"2018-08-03T090018 SBE0251090", "2018-08-03T090018 SBE0251090", 
"2018-08-03T090018 SBE0251090", "2018-08-03T090018 SBE0251090", 
"2018-08-03T090018 SBE0251090"), station = c("1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", 
"2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3"), month = c(8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L), day = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L), year = c(2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L
), time = c(16.38, 16.38, 16.38, 16.38, 16.38, 16.38, 16.38, 
16.38, 16.38, 16.38, 17.57, 17.57, 17.57, 17.57, 17.57, 17.57, 
17.57, 17.57, 17.57, 17.57, 9.05, 9.05, 9.05, 9.05, 9.05), LAT = c("69.27166667", 
"69.27166667", "69.27166667", "69.27166667", "69.27166667", "69.27166667", 
"69.27166667", "69.27166667", "69.27166667", "69.27166667", "69.25386667", 
"69.25386667", "69.25386667", "69.25386667", "69.25386667", "69.25386667", 
"69.25386667", "69.25386667", "69.25386667", "69.25386667", "69.23883333", 
"69.23883333", "69.23883333", "69.23883333", "69.23883333"), 
    LONG = c("-25.15166667", "-25.15166667", "-25.15166667", 
    "-25.15166667", "-25.15166667", "-25.15166667", "-25.15166667", 
    "-25.15166667", "-25.15166667", "-25.15166667", "-25.0637", 
    "-25.0637", "-25.0637", "-25.0637", "-25.0637", "-25.0637", 
    "-25.0637", "-25.0637", "-25.0637", "-25.0637", "-24.9915", 
    "-24.9915", "-24.9915", "-24.9915", "-24.9915"), bottom_depth = c("226", 
    "226", "226", "226", "226", "226", "226", "226", "226", "226", 
    "229", "229", "229", "229", "229", "229", "229", "229", "229", 
    "229", "255", "255", "255", "255", "255"), timeS = c(223.5, 
    227.236, 228.558, 228.916, 229.336, 229.749, 230.119, 230.49, 
    228.871, 231.587, 242.497, 241.334, 241.591, 241.869, 242.205, 
    242.601, 249.68, 249.758, 250.013, 250.3, 266.6, 267.148, 
    267.57, 267.899, 268.245), pressure = c(0.607, 0.707, 0.808, 
    0.909, 1.01, 1.112, 1.212, 1.313, 1.516, 1.616, 0.503, 0.101, 
    0.202, 0.303, 0.404, 0.505, 0.606, 0.707, 0.808, 0.909, 0.303, 
    0.404, 0.505, 0.606, 0.707), depth = c(0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 
    1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.5, 1.6, 0.5, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 
    0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7), salinity = c(30.195, 
    30.1989, 30.199, 30.1737, 30.1894, 30.1824, 30.1546, 30.2275, 
    29.9942, 30.2885, 28.2285, 28.1332, 28.2182, 28.3279, 28.3815, 
    28.4242, 29.0786, 29.1525, 29.2647, 29.3672, 32.484, 32.3028, 
    31.885, 31.3775, 30.978), temperature = c(2.6459, 2.6477, 
    2.6263, 2.5913, 2.6188, 2.608, 2.6106, 2.6746, 2.6973, 2.6837, 
    1.9945, 2.0299, 1.9315, 1.7799, 1.734, 1.7082, 1.9263, 1.928, 
    1.9184, 1.8562, 1.1441, 1.073, 1.052, 1.0518, 1.0603), oxygen = c(352.891, 
    352.339, 352.12, 352.03, 351.884, 351.702, 351.505, 351.296, 
    347.288, 351.001, 345.827, 345.879, 345.866, 345.841, 345.782, 
    345.65, 346.849, 346.78, 346.718, 346.609, 340.888, 340.026, 
    339.348, 338.819, 338.245), oxygen2 = c(102.182, 102.228, 
    102.257, 102.281, 102.313, 102.347, 102.383, 102.427, 101.491, 
    102.644, 97.258, 97.311, 97.301, 97.29, 97.275, 97.253, 98.285, 
    98.293, 98.325, 98.357, 97.857, 97.839, 97.829, 97.812, 97.788
    ), fluorescence = c(0.17892, 0.17232, 0.17139, 0.17278, 0.17479, 
    0.17701, 0.1792, 0.18158, 0.18525, 0.18909, 0.10588, 0.10647, 
    0.10697, 0.10818, 0.10978, 0.11157, 0.1479, 0.14969, 0.15256, 
    0.15607, 0.30833, 0.31088, 0.31321, 0.31532, 0.31758), turbidity = c(0.164, 
    0.164, 0.164, 0.164, 0.163, 0.163, 0.163, 0.163, 0.161, 0.163, 
    0.165, 0.165, 0.165, 0.165, 0.165, 0.164, 0.159, 0.16, 0.16, 
    0.16, 4.742, 4.747, 4.751, 4.753, 4.755), conductivity = c(2.742475, 
    2.743057, 2.74087, 2.73591, 2.740138, 2.738197, 2.736985, 
    2.747572, 2.72913, 2.752912, 2.524555, 2.525942, 2.524426, 
    2.523692, 2.525012, 2.526692, 2.596153, 2.602249, 2.609861, 
    2.613963, 2.806078, 2.786396, 2.752134, 2.712379, 2.682113
    ), pH = c(8.094, 8.098, 8.099, 8.099, 8.099, 8.099, 8.099, 
    8.099, 8.014, 8.099, 8.16, 8.16, 8.16, 8.16, 8.159, 8.159, 
    8.149, 8.148, 8.147, 8.146, 8.121, 8.12, 8.12, 8.119, 8.118
    ), par = c(2627.7, 2627.7, 2627.7, 2627.7, 2627.7, 2627.7, 
    2627.7, 2627.7, 2600, 2627.7, 2627.8, 2627.8, 2627.8, 2627.8, 
    2627.8, 2627.8, 2627.8, 2627.8, 2627.8, 2627.8, 2627.6, NA, 
    2627.6, 2627.6, 2627.6), soundSpeed = c(1454.65, 1454.65, 
    1454.57, 1454.38, 1454.53, 1454.47, 1454.45, 1454.82, 1439.8, 
    1454.96, 1449.08, 1449.22, 1448.88, 1448.36, 1448.23, 1448.18, 
    1449.98, 1450.1, 1450.19, 1450.08, 1450.99, 1450.48, 1449.83, 
    1449.19, 1448.69), svDM = c(1454.55, 1454.55, 1454.48, 1454.29, 
    1454.43, 1454.37, 1454.35, 1454.72, 1439.71, 1454.86, 1448.98, 
    1449.12, 1448.78, 1448.26, 1448.14, 1448.08, 1449.89, 1450.01, 
    1450.1, 1449.98, 1450.91, 1450.4, 1449.76, 1449.12, 1448.61
    ), svWM = c(1454.57, 1454.57, 1454.49, 1454.3, 1454.45, 1454.39, 
    1454.37, 1454.74, 1439.73, 1454.89, 1448.89, 1449.03, 1448.69, 
    1448.18, 1448.05, 1448, 1449.84, 1449.96, 1450.05, 1449.94, 
      1451.01, 1450.49, 1449.83, 1449.16, 1448.62)), row.names = c(NA, 
    25L), class = "data.frame")

#to correspond to the number of observations, the rows are duplicated

    PdataLaKo <- as.data.frame(lapply(PdataLaKo, rep, 250))
```

To do that I used, the function `group_split` from the package `dplyr`, which created a tibble of different lists corresponding to each group (ctd_file). after I tried to apply `shapiro.test` from the package `rstatix` to each selected variable of a group with `sapply` and to each groups with `lapply`.

```
PdataLaKo <- PdataLaKo %>%
  group_split(ctd_file)
lnorm <- PdataLaKo[, c(11:24)] %>% 
  map(~ lapply(., sapply(., shapiro.test)))
```

If I extract one group with filter and do not create a tibble, the `sapply` function applied to each variable works. Consequently, the problem come from tibble and not the application to selected column.

```
#non-grouped data
PdataLaKot <- PdataLaKo %>% filter(ctd_file == "2018-08-05T092503 SBE0251090")    
lnorm <- PdataLaKot[, c(11:24)] %>% sapply(shapiro.test)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
library(tidyverse)

shapiro_test_safely <- possibly(.f = shapiro.test, otherwise = NA)

a <- df %>%
  group_nest(ctd_file) %>% 
  mutate(
    data = map(data, ~select(.x, where(is.numeric))[, -c(1:4)]),
    res = map(data, ~map(.x, shapiro_test_safely)),
    res = purrr::set_names(res, nm = ctd_file))

fltr <- map(a$res, ~!is.na(.x))

b <- map2(.x = a$res, .y = fltr,  ~.x[.y])

map_df(b, ~map_df(.x, broom::glance)) %>% 
  mutate(nm = map(b, names) %>% unlist()) %>% 
  mutate(SET = rep(names(b), sapply(b, length))) 

#> # A tibble: 43 x 5
#>    statistic p.value method                      nm           SET               
#>        <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>                       <chr>        <chr>             
#>  1     0.862 0.0807  Shapiro-Wilk normality test timeS        2018-08-02T162038~
#>  2     0.969 0.879   Shapiro-Wilk normality test pressure     2018-08-02T162038~
#>  3     0.969 0.882   Shapiro-Wilk normality test depth        2018-08-02T162038~
#>  4     0.800 0.0144  Shapiro-Wilk normality test salinity     2018-08-02T162038~
#>  5     0.946 0.625   Shapiro-Wilk normality test temperature  2018-08-02T162038~
#>  6     0.711 0.00119 Shapiro-Wilk normality test oxygen       2018-08-02T162038~
#>  7     0.776 0.00738 Shapiro-Wilk normality test oxygen2      2018-08-02T162038~
#>  8     0.939 0.543   Shapiro-Wilk normality test fluorescence 2018-08-02T162038~
#>  9     0.750 0.00356 Shapiro-Wilk normality test turbidity    2018-08-02T162038~
#> 10     0.978 0.954   Shapiro-Wilk normality test conductivity 2018-08-02T162038~
#> # ... with 33 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

**data**

```
df <-
  structure(
    list(
      ctd_file = c(
        "2018-08-02T162038 SBE0251090",
        "2018-08-02T162038 SBE0251090",
        "2018-08-02T162038 SBE0251090",
        "2018-08-02T162038 SBE0251090",
        "2018-08-02T162038 SBE0251090",
        "2018-08-02T162038 SBE0251090",
        "2018-08-02T162038 SBE0251090",
        "2018-08-02T162038 SBE0251090",
        "2018-08-02T162038 SBE0251090",
        "2018-08-02T162038 SBE0251090",
        "2018-08-02T175518 SBE0251090",
        "2018-08-02T175518 SBE0251090",
        "2018-08-02T175518 SBE0251090",
        "2018-08-02T175518 SBE0251090",
        "2018-08-02T175518 SBE0251090",
        "2018-08-02T175518 SBE0251090",
        "2018-08-02T175518 SBE0251090",
        "2018-08-02T175518 SBE0251090",
        "2018-08-02T175518 SBE0251090",
        "2018-08-02T175518 SBE0251090",
        "2018-08-03T090018 SBE0251090",
        "2018-08-03T090018 SBE0251090",
        "2018-08-03T090018 SBE0251090",
        "2018-08-03T090018 SBE0251090",
        "2018-08-03T090018 SBE0251090"
      ),
      station = c(
        "1",
        "1",
        "1",
        "1",
        "1",
        "1",
        "1",
        "1",
        "1",
        "1",
        "2",
        "2",
        "2",
        "2",
        "2",
        "2",
        "2",
        "2",
        "2",
        "2",
        "3",
        "3",
        "3",
        "3",
        "3"
      ),
      month = c(
        8L,
        8L,
        8L,
        8L,
        8L,
        8L,
        8L,
        8L,
        8L,
        8L,
        8L,
        8L,
        8L,
        8L,
        8L,
        8L,
        8L,
        8L,
        8L,
        8L,
        8L,
        8L,
        8L,
        8L,
        8L
      ),
      day = c(
        2L,
        2L,
        2L,
        2L,
        2L,
        2L,
        2L,
        2L,
        2L,
        2L,
        2L,
        2L,
        2L,
        2L,
        2L,
        2L,
        2L,
        2L,
        2L,
        2L,
        3L,
        3L,
        3L,
        3L,
        3L
      ),
      year = c(
        2018L,
        2018L,
        2018L,
        2018L,
        2018L,
        2018L,
        2018L,
        2018L,
        2018L,
        2018L,
        2018L,
        2018L,
        2018L,
        2018L,
        2018L,
        2018L,
        2018L,
        2018L,
        2018L,
        2018L,
        2018L,
        2018L,
        2018L,
        2018L,
        2018L
      ),
      time = c(
        16.38,
        16.38,
        16.38,
        16.38,
        16.38,
        16.38,
        16.38,
        16.38,
        16.38,
        16.38,
        17.57,
        17.57,
        17.57,
        17.57,
        17.57,
        17.57,
        17.57,
        17.57,
        17.57,
        17.57,
        9.05,
        9.05,
        9.05,
        9.05,
        9.05
      ),
      LAT = c(
        "69.27166667",
        "69.27166667",
        "69.27166667",
        "69.27166667",
        "69.27166667",
        "69.27166667",
        "69.27166667",
        "69.27166667",
        "69.27166667",
        "69.27166667",
        "69.25386667",
        "69.25386667",
        "69.25386667",
        "69.25386667",
        "69.25386667",
        "69.25386667",
        "69.25386667",
        "69.25386667",
        "69.25386667",
        "69.25386667",
        "69.23883333",
        "69.23883333",
        "69.23883333",
        "69.23883333",
        "69.23883333"
      ),
      LONG = c(
        "-25.15166667",
        "-25.15166667",
        "-25.15166667",
        "-25.15166667",
        "-25.15166667",
        "-25.15166667",
        "-25.15166667",
        "-25.15166667",
        "-25.15166667",
        "-25.15166667",
        "-25.0637",
        "-25.0637",
        "-25.0637",
        "-25.0637",
        "-25.0637",
        "-25.0637",
        "-25.0637",
        "-25.0637",
        "-25.0637",
        "-25.0637",
        "-24.9915",
        "-24.9915",
        "-24.9915",
        "-24.9915",
        "-24.9915"
      ),
      bottom_depth = c(
        "226",
        "226",
        "226",
        "226",
        "226",
        "226",
        "226",
        "226",
        "226",
        "226",
        "229",
        "229",
        "229",
        "229",
        "229",
        "229",
        "229",
        "229",
        "229",
        "229",
        "255",
        "255",
        "255",
        "255",
        "255"
      ),
      timeS = c(
        223.5,
        227.236,
        228.558,
        228.916,
        229.336,
        229.749,
        230.119,
        230.49,
        228.871,
        231.587,
        242.497,
        241.334,
        241.591,
        241.869,
        242.205,
        242.601,
        249.68,
        249.758,
        250.013,
        250.3,
        266.6,
        267.148,
        267.57,
        267.899,
        268.245
      ),
      pressure = c(
        0.607,
        0.707,
        0.808,
        0.909,
        1.01,
        1.112,
        1.212,
        1.313,
        1.516,
        1.616,
        0.503,
        0.101,
        0.202,
        0.303,
        0.404,
        0.505,
        0.606,
        0.707,
        0.808,
        0.909,
        0.303,
        0.404,
        0.505,
        0.606,
        0.707
      ),
      depth = c(
        0.6,
        0.7,
        0.8,
        0.9,
        1,
        1.1,
        1.2,
        1.3,
        1.5,
        1.6,
        0.5,
        0.1,
        0.2,
        0.3,
        0.4,
        0.5,
        0.6,
        0.7,
        0.8,
        0.9,
        0.3,
        0.4,
        0.5,
        0.6,
        0.7
      ),
      salinity = c(
        30.195,
        30.1989,
        30.199,
        30.1737,
        30.1894,
        30.1824,
        30.1546,
        30.2275,
        29.9942,
        30.2885,
        28.2285,
        28.1332,
        28.2182,
        28.3279,
        28.3815,
        28.4242,
        29.0786,
        29.1525,
        29.2647,
        29.3672,
        32.484,
        32.3028,
        31.885,
        31.3775,
        30.978
      ),
      temperature = c(
        2.6459,
        2.6477,
        2.6263,
        2.5913,
        2.6188,
        2.608,
        2.6106,
        2.6746,
        2.6973,
        2.6837,
        1.9945,
        2.0299,
        1.9315,
        1.7799,
        1.734,
        1.7082,
        1.9263,
        1.928,
        1.9184,
        1.8562,
        1.1441,
        1.073,
        1.052,
        1.0518,
        1.0603
      ),
      oxygen = c(
        352.891,
        352.339,
        352.12,
        352.03,
        351.884,
        351.702,
        351.505,
        351.296,
        347.288,
        351.001,
        345.827,
        345.879,
        345.866,
        345.841,
        345.782,
        345.65,
        346.849,
        346.78,
        346.718,
        346.609,
        340.888,
        340.026,
        339.348,
        338.819,
        338.245
      ),
      oxygen2 = c(
        102.182,
        102.228,
        102.257,
        102.281,
        102.313,
        102.347,
        102.383,
        102.427,
        101.491,
        102.644,
        97.258,
        97.311,
        97.301,
        97.29,
        97.275,
        97.253,
        98.285,
        98.293,
        98.325,
        98.357,
        97.857,
        97.839,
        97.829,
        97.812,
        97.788
      ),
      fluorescence = c(
        0.17892,
        0.17232,
        0.17139,
        0.17278,
        0.17479,
        0.17701,
        0.1792,
        0.18158,
        0.18525,
        0.18909,
        0.10588,
        0.10647,
        0.10697,
        0.10818,
        0.10978,
        0.11157,
        0.1479,
        0.14969,
        0.15256,
        0.15607,
        0.30833,
        0.31088,
        0.31321,
        0.31532,
        0.31758
      ),
      turbidity = c(
        0.164,
        0.164,
        0.164,
        0.164,
        0.163,
        0.163,
        0.163,
        0.163,
        0.161,
        0.163,
        0.165,
        0.165,
        0.165,
        0.165,
        0.165,
        0.164,
        0.159,
        0.16,
        0.16,
        0.16,
        4.742,
        4.747,
        4.751,
        4.753,
        4.755
      ),
      conductivity = c(
        2.742475,
        2.743057,
        2.74087,
        2.73591,
        2.740138,
        2.738197,
        2.736985,
        2.747572,
        2.72913,
        2.752912,
        2.524555,
        2.525942,
        2.524426,
        2.523692,
        2.525012,
        2.526692,
        2.596153,
        2.602249,
        2.609861,
        2.613963,
        2.806078,
        2.786396,
        2.752134,
        2.712379,
        2.682113
      ),
      pH = c(
        8.094,
        8.098,
        8.099,
        8.099,
        8.099,
        8.099,
        8.099,
        8.099,
        8.014,
        8.099,
        8.16,
        8.16,
        8.16,
        8.16,
        8.159,
        8.159,
        8.149,
        8.148,
        8.147,
        8.146,
        8.121,
        8.12,
        8.12,
        8.119,
        8.118
      ),
      par = c(
        2627.7,
        2627.7,
        2627.7,
        2627.7,
        2627.7,
        2627.7,
        2627.7,
        2627.7,
        2600,
        2627.7,
        2627.8,
        2627.8,
        2627.8,
        2627.8,
        2627.8,
        2627.8,
        2627.8,
        2627.8,
        2627.8,
        2627.8,
        2627.6,
        NA,
        2627.6,
        2627.6,
        2627.6
      ),
      soundSpeed = c(
        1454.65,
        1454.65,
        1454.57,
        1454.38,
        1454.53,
        1454.47,
        1454.45,
        1454.82,
        1439.8,
        1454.96,
        1449.08,
        1449.22,
        1448.88,
        1448.36,
        1448.23,
        1448.18,
        1449.98,
        1450.1,
        1450.19,
        1450.08,
        1450.99,
        1450.48,
        1449.83,
        1449.19,
        1448.69
      ),
      svDM = c(
        1454.55,
        1454.55,
        1454.48,
        1454.29,
        1454.43,
        1454.37,
        1454.35,
        1454.72,
        1439.71,
        1454.86,
        1448.98,
        1449.12,
        1448.78,
        1448.26,
        1448.14,
        1448.08,
        1449.89,
        1450.01,
        1450.1,
        1449.98,
        1450.91,
        1450.4,
        1449.76,
        1449.12,
        1448.61
      ),
      svWM = c(
        1454.57,
        1454.57,
        1454.49,
        1454.3,
        1454.45,
        1454.39,
        1454.37,
        1454.74,
        1439.73,
        1454.89,
        1448.89,
        1449.03,
        1448.69,
        1448.18,
        1448.05,
        1448,
        1449.84,
        1449.96,
        1450.05,
        1449.94,
        1451.01,
        1450.49,
        1449.83,
        1449.16,
        1448.62
      )
    ),
    row.names = c(NA,
                  25L),
    class = "data.frame"
  )
```

Comment: Really interesting answer, that works perfectly. Moreover, one other interest in your code is it automatically avoiding the non-numerical variables.

Comment: Great! If you believe this answer was helpful for you, you could accept it by clicking the tick on the left side of this answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Generally you could do this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(rstatix)

PdataLaKo %>% 
  group_by(ctd_file) %>% 
  summarize(across(pressure:svWM, ~ list(shapiro_test(.))),
            .groups = "drop")
```

However, in your code you're using `shaprio.test` which is from base `R` not `shapiro_test` from the `rstatix` library.

Also, with the example you've provided this code will error because some of your columns for certain groups do not have any variation in their data. Excluding those columns the output would look like this:

```
lnorm <- PdataLaKo %>% 
  group_by(ctd_file) %>% 
  summarize(across(pressure:pH, ~ list(shapiro_test(.))), # range only up to pH
            .groups = "drop")

lnorm
# A tibble: 3 x 11
  ctd_file   pressure  depth  salinity temperature oxygen oxygen2 fluorescence
  <chr>      <list>    <list> <list>   <list>      <list> <list>  <list>      
1 2018-08-0~ <tibble ~ <tibb~ <tibble~ <tibble [1~ <tibb~ <tibbl~ <tibble [1 ~
2 2018-08-0~ <tibble ~ <tibb~ <tibble~ <tibble [1~ <tibb~ <tibbl~ <tibble [1 ~
3 2018-08-0~ <tibble ~ <tibb~ <tibble~ <tibble [1~ <tibb~ <tibbl~ <tibble [1 ~
# ... with 3 more variables: turbidity <list>, conductivity <list>, pH <list>
```

Note that the output is a bunch of list-columns and each list contains a tibble of the results from the test. You could then access a specific group and column in multiple ways (below using row index and column names):

```
lnorm[1, "pressure", drop = T][[1]]
# A tibble: 1 x 3
  variable statistic  p.value
  <chr>        <dbl>    <dbl>
1 pressure     0.934 5.66e-32
```

Comment: Thank you @LMc for my data set I had also to filter an empty ctd_file and I few groups contained to much observation. Then I added this code.
`PdataLaKo <- PdataLaKo %>% 
  filter(ctd_file != "") %>%
  group_by(ctd_file) %>%
  filter(row_number() %in% 1:4999)`
But I really like the simplicity of your code.